# How can I use wget to download a list of URLs and sort them according to a second data field?

Tags: bash, wget

I am very new to coding or doing anything like this.  I have a list of several thousand URLs in excel.  Each URL is associated with one of approximately 300 numbers.  I have it as one column is the URL, and the next column is the number that that URL is associated with.  For example, I have five URLs associated with the number 1, four URLs associated with the number 2, etc.  I am trying to download the files that are found at the URL but maintain the organization that I have through the associated numbers.  So I am trying to get all of the files from URLs associated with 1 into a folder, all of the files form URLs associated with 2 into a separate folder, etc.

I believe that using bash scripting and wget is the pathway towards this, but I am struggling to figure out the correct series of commands.  I would appreciate any help people could give me.

I don't expect anybody to just do this for me, but I would appreciate any helpful hints or useful resources or guides that people could point me towards.  Thanks!

I believe that saving my excel sheet as CSV would be part of the correct path forwards, but I have very little idea of what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

Generally folks are expected to post what they've tried so far. But since you're brand new here, let's see if we can at least get you off the ground.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Example input file urls.csv
# http://foo.com,2
# http://bar.com,7
# Reference for the "wget" command I used - https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2014/05/02/make-offline-mirror-of-a-site-using-wget/

#
# Split the file on the comma and loop through the url / ID pairs
#
awk -F, '{print $1" "$2}' urls.csv | while read url id
do
   echo "Getting url $url ID $id"
   #
   # Make the directory if it doesn't exist, and change directory into it
   #
   if [ ! -d $id ]; then
      mkdir $id
   fi
   cd $id
   #
   # Execute the wget
   #
   wget --mirror --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --no-parent $url
   #
   # Change directory back up to the parent
   #
   cd ..
done
```